# Should module import structures avoid dragging intermediate modules into higher namespaces? If so, how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

Say I have a module like this:

```
module
├── __init__.py
└── submodule
    ├── B.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── subsubmodule
        ├── A.py
        └── __init__.py
```

With the following file contents:

```
module/submodule/subsubmodule/A.py
    class A:
        pass

module/submodule/subsubmodule/__init__.py
    from .A import A

module/submodule/__init__.py
    from .subsubmodule import A
    from .B import B

module/submodule/B.py
    class B:
        pass

module/__init__.py
    from .submodule import A, B
```

When I import the module, I want the classes `A` and `B` to be available immediately at the top level. That works the way I set it up just fine. But I also end up with `submodule` in the namespace of `module`. Why? Is that ok or a problem? It looks unclean to me. Can I avoid this?

```
In [1]: import module

In [2]: dir(module)
Out[2]: 
['A',
 'B',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'submodule'] # <------------ why is that here?
```

I said `from .submodule import A, B` in the `__init__.py` of `module`. I never said `from . import submodule`. So intermediate modules are dragged into the namespace apparently. Should this be avoided and if so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I said from .submodule import A, B in the **init**.py of module. I never said from . import submodule. So intermediate modules are dragged into the namespace apparently. Should this be avoided and if so how.

Nothing is "dragged into the namespace", "submodule" IS a part of "module"s namespace because "submodule" is a part of "module", that is why in the **init** of module you can do; "from (DOT)submodule ..".

The dot translates to "from THISPACKAGE->submodule ..."

If "submodule" was not part of the "module" package then you wouldn't be able to import it FROM "module" inside module's **init**.

Comment: I guess I assumed the dot syntax was referring to the folder rather than a module. What if I have an intermediate directory that I do not want showing in the namespace? For example an `incl` folder inside `submodule`.

Comment: @lotolmencre Whenever you import "module" you are importing everything it contains along with it. If you have a module or package which "module" relies on, but which you don't want to have as part of "module" then the **cough cough** ""Correct"" **cough cough** way of doing it would be to refactor that module/package out of "module" and then import it into "module" where it is needed. However if you really want "submodule" to be defined INSIDE module, but you don't want it to show up when you do "dir" then you need to redefine "\_\_dir__" inside the module "\_\_init__.py".

Comment: .. But the latter is more of a "hack" than an actual solution, and I don't know why you would even bother with that. Keep in mind that you are importing "submodule" whenever you import "module" pretty much regardless of what you do, redefining "\_\_dir__" would just let you hide it from the outside world..

Comment: cool, sounds like what I want to do. Why would it be a bad idea though? I see nothing wrong with having subfolders like `incl` that should be hidden from the user. What issue do you see there?

Comment: @lotolmencre IMPO if all you want to do is "hide" some internals of a package from the user then what you should do is just put an "\_" (Underscore) in from of the name, this is the common-practice way to indicate that something is private in Python. or you can even start the name off with "\_\_" ("dunder"/ "double-underscore") which will let you take advantage of Pythons name-mangling (out of the scope of this comment, look it up..).. But if you really want to HIDE the internal module then be my guest, redefine "\_\_dir__" as you like, It is just not normally something you would do.

Comment: Oh and BTW!!! You can only redefine "\_\_dir__" in Python versions 3.7 and above!